# Pandas extract substring with optional in pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

From a df column 'Desc' I want to extract substrings that start with n or N followed by a digit, here's a test df with my code and result:

```
import pandas as pd
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'Desc': ['n1.2A Full Version', 'N5.0.0 Bridge', 'N5.35A Automatic', 'n2 Bridge']})
testdf['Version'] = testdf['Desc'].str.extract(r'([nN]\d.+?[\s])', expand=False)
```

How to fix the regex so that it doesn't show NaN for the last record? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `.+?` requires at least 1 char other than line break char and then `[\s]` requires a whitespace to match. So, when `[nN]\d` matched and consumed `n2`, the regex engine tries to match the next space with `.+?` and then `[\s]` fails to match a whitespace.

You may  use

```
>>> testdf['Desc'].str.extract(r'([nN]\d\S*)', expand=False)
0     n1.2A
1    N5.0.0
2    N5.35A
3        n2
```

The pattern is `[nN]\d\S*`:

- `[nN]` - `n` or `N`
- `\d` - a digit
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars

See [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cZqPX5/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5BnN%5D%5Cd%5CS*)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one clarification - which bit of the regex stops it at the first white-space?

Comment: @shanlodh `\S*` - it matches only non-whitespace chars.

Comment: OK, thanks, I could have also used `r'([nN]\d.*?[\s])` in that case but obviously your solution is much clearer

Comment: @shanlodh With `r'([nN]\d.*?[\s])`, you will never find a match at the end of the string.